ability to change the camera angle in AnyLogic
I'm using AnyLogic to simulate camera operation on a conveyor and faced a problem. In the 3D camera settings I did not find an option to change the field of view (FOV). In the documentation and interface I didn't find the corresponding parameter either.
Is it possible to change the viewing angle of a 3D camera using code in AnyLogic? If it is possible, how can it be realized?
I will be grateful for any help!

Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Only use the "anylogic" tag to not confuse other SOF users, pls :)

use an agent as your cameraman


In the 3D camera settings I did not find an option to change the field of view (FOV)

there is none

Is it possible to change the viewing angle of a 3D camera using code in AnyLogic?

As far as what the API allows you, such as:

Beyond that, you can manually create different cameras with different angles and switch programmatically via your 3D window (myWindow.setCamera(...))
